# Converting counts to individual observations in r

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks as follows

```
df <- data.frame( name = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  judgement1= c(5, 0, NA),
                  judgement2= c(1, 1, NA),
                  judgement3= c(2, 1, NA))
```

I want to reshape the dataframe to look like this

```
# name  judgement1 judgement2 judgement3
# a         1          0          0
# a         1          0          0
# a         1          0          0
# a         1          0          0
# a         1          0          0
# b         1          0          0  
# b         0          1          0  
# b         0          0          1
```

And so on. I have seen that untable is recommended on some other threads, but it does not appear to work with the current version of r. Is there a package that can convert summarised counts into individual observations?

Comment: Are you sure that is the wanted output? If so, please explain the rules to get that output.

Comment: Yes. I am sure. The rule would be to expand  the value in each judgement column, so that there is one observation per row.

Comment: @user183974 S Rivero is pointing out that there should be 3 more name: a rows for judgement2 and judgement3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
df <- data.frame( name = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  judgement1= c(5, 0, NA),
                  judgement2= c(1, 1, NA),
                  judgement3= c(2, 1, NA))

rep.vec <- colSums(df[colnames(df) %in% paste0("judgement", (1:nrow(df)), sep="")], na.rm = TRUE)
want <- data.frame(name=df$name, cbind(diag(nrow(df))))
colnames(want)[-1] <- paste0("judgement", (1:nrow(df)), sep="")
(want <- want[rep(1:nrow(want), rep.vec), ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function that works to give you your desired output:

```
untabl <- function(df, id.col, count.cols) {
  df[is.na(df)] <- 0                          # replace NAs
  out <- lapply(count.cols, function(x) {     # for each column with counts
    z <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), df[,x]), ]        # replicate rows
    z[, -c(id.col)] <- 0                      # set all other columns to zero
    z[, x] <- 1                               # replace the count values with 1 
    z
  })
  out <- do.call(rbind, out) # combine the list
  out <- out[order(out[,c(id.col)]),] # reorder (you can change this)
  rownames(out) <- NULL # return to simple row numbers
  out
}

untabl(df = df, id.col = 1, count.cols = c(2,3,4))
#   name judgement1 judgement2 judgement3
#1     a          1          0          0
#2     a          1          0          0
#3     a          1          0          0
#4     a          1          0          0
#5     a          1          0          0
#6     a          0          1          0
#7     b          0          1          0
#8     a          0          0          1
#9     a          0          0          1
#10    b          0          0          1
```

And for your reference, reshape::untable consists of the following code:

```
function (df, num) 
{
    df[rep(1:nrow(df), num), ]
}
```